# Excel 2013 compare dates on different row using macro "Run time error 13, Type mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba, macros, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I'm new in vba, currently I'm working and my boss need me to create a excel macro.

The macro function are:

- compare data are dates, Start date with End date.
- auto remind user employees contract outdated when open worksheet.
- if employees contract outdated, highlight employees details.

So now I'm stuck until "Run time error 13, Type mismatch".

Below are my codding part, mismatch is between >>>  <<<.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngD As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rngA In .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    For Each rngD In .Range(.Range("D1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))

        >>> If rngA.Value("A1:xlUp") >= rngD.Value("D1:xlUp") Then <<<
            MsgBox "Sheet 1 Row " & rngA.Row & " expiring"
            rngC.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            rngC.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            rngC.Font.Bold = True

        End If


    Next rngD
    Next rngA


End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `If rngA.Value >= rngD.Value Then`

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting? Also noting that your code is looking at column A and column D in the same row (which is different ti what you explain in your question).

Comment: Thank you for the asap reply, but I'm not understand about your suggestion....@@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And Range("D" & i).Value <> "" Then
        If Range("A" & i).Value >= Range("D" & i).Value Then
            Range("C" & i).Value = "Contract Going to Expire"
            Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = 3
            Range("C" & i).Font.ColorIndex = 2
            Range("C" & i).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

End With

Comment: yeap~! it is working!...but dude...I sill trying to add in the message box,
so far I just added in this 


           MsgBox "Sheet 1 Row " & Range("A" & i) & " expiring"

The MsgBox is working.

Comment: By he way, can i know about the meaning of your codding?

>>>Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Row  <<< what does it means? How about if i wan to start counting at H4 to the end rather than H1? How should i modify he codding?
Looking forward for your reply. thx

Comment: @Han, it means to find the last non-empty row from the bottom of the excel sheet of specific column.